# Basis Authentication Protocol: a concrete attack

Tags: authentication, attacks, attack-prevention, protocols

Below is an informal protocol narration of a simple authentication protocol. A sends to B a signed hash of message M, B's name and a nonce N. B knows that the message M is intended for him, that it originates from A and that it was sent as part of the same run.

```
A -> B: (M, A)
B -> A: N
A -> B: {| #(M,B,N) |}sA
```

But what will happen if we omit B's name?

```
A -> B: (M, A)
B -> A: N
A -> B: {| #(M,N) |}sA
```

I cannot think of a concrete scenario with a harmful attack. What attack could cause harm? A possible scenario is listed below:

```
A -> B: (M, A)
B -> A: N
A -> I: {| #(M,N) |}sA
I -> B: {| #(M,N) |}sA
```

There is no proof that the message was intended for B. So, intruder I can intercept the message signed by A and redirect it to B, authenticating I as A. But what is a harmful attack? For example in a bank-client interaction scenario?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no proof that the message was intended for B. So, intruder I can intercept the message signed by A and redirect it to B, authenticating I as A. But what is a harmful attack? For example in a bank-client interaction scenario?

If I understand you correctly, you've just described the first part of a Man In The Middle ([MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)) attack.